# Inkscape - Make dashes the same length

Tags: inkscape

I'm trying to make a dashed octagon, with dashes with the same length in all the corners, but I can't make all the dashes have the same length so the dashes can't get aligned exactly in the corners.

[image: Octagon logo]

**Example of what I'm trying to achieve:**

[image: Dashed triangle]

Comment: I'm not sure if this exists in Inkscape, but in Illustrator you can just make a hexagon and apply a dashed line stroke.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is a gif to explain breaking the octagon apart so you are working on 8 lines should be a bit easier. Tweak the size of the stroke , the different dash lines, and that dash adjuster

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**You have complete control**, if you make one straight dashed line as a grouped shape which you copy, rotate and place to form a polygon. Inkscape has well working snaps to place the ends exactly.

An example:

[image]

Red parts will be spaces, they can be removed as soon as the parts of one line are placed. I let them to be grouped with the other parts and removed them at the end, when the groups were ungrouped

Pentagon needs copies, which are rotated 72, 144, 216 and 288 degrees. For octagon the angles would be multiples of 45 degrees.

Green parts are 50% shorter than the black parts. At the cusps the green parts are finally joined with the node tool. No joining is needed, if you have rounded line caps.